# Does Azure Policies using JSON let you check for a VM extension by it's name?

Tags: json, azure, virtual-machine, azure-policy

I'm currently using the following exsistance condition:

```
    "existenceCondition": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "field": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions/instanceView.name",
          "equals": "customextensionname"
        },
        {
          "field": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions/publisher",
          "equals": "Microsoft.Compute"
        },
        {
          "field": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions/provisioningState",
          "equals": "Succeeded"
        }
      ]
```

I tried using extension/name and I get an error that it's not available. My policy checks for all windows VMs, but I'm not sure how to check the name of the extension. It's there, but it reports non compliant and that there is no value for instanceView.name..

Answer (score 0):

i think it should be something like this:

```
{
    "field": "type",
    "equals": "Microsoft.Compute/VirtualMachines/extensions"
},
{
    "not": {
        "field": "name",
        "equals": "customextensionname"
    }
}
```

Comment: I feel like because it's checking for windows VMs, it would check the name of the VM and not the name of the extension

Comment: why? you specify the type of the resource in this example

Comment: Is this in the existence condition?

Comment: what "this"? where you specify the type, this would mean all the other properties are checked for that object. else it makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an alias for `name`. [It's a supported top level field](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/concepts/definition-structure#fields). Within the existence condition it will refer to the related resource - the extension in your case - not the evaluated resource.

Your existence condition will work like this:

```
    "existenceCondition": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "field": "name",
          "equals": "customextensionname"
        },
        {
          "field": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions/publisher",
          "equals": "Microsoft.Compute"
        },
        {
          "field": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions/provisioningState",
          "equals": "Succeeded"
        }
      ]
```